# How to set up browser caching for static elements (css, js, images)

Tags: html, django, apache, caching

Just to be specific i'm using django and apache server.

I'm getting these messages when testing a site on pingdom tools.

The following cache able resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at       least one week in the future for the following resources:

```
http://site.com/static/css/style.css
http://site.com/static/images/facebook_f_icon.png
http://site.com/static/images/logo.png
```

etc...

Tried googling the issue but it was pretty unclear. How should I set up browser caching along with an expiration date for these elements? Is this in the form of an html tag? Do i need to configure apache? Where are the settings?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html.